# How to make 3d effect

Tags: vector, 3d

I have a flat version of the image below (flat = just black, without 3d effect),
I need to make it look the same as the image below. To me it looks like some automatic (effect) rendering has been used. Is that true?

And what effect rendering was used, or what effect rendering could result in the same 3d effect?

[image: Should be result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example image is small and not very clear, but it looks like what you're referring to is a simple bevel effect. You don't mention any specific software so I'll show you a quick example in Photoshop but you can probably find a similar effect in most image editors.

Start with your solid shape:

[image]

From the Layer Style dialog select Bevel & Emboss and choose an "Inner Bevel" and "Chisel Hard", adjust the size and lighting to your liking:

[image]

Your finished bevel effect:

[image]